# How to call arbitrary C++ functions from QML right at the object's creation?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Here's my main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import A 1.0

Item {

    width: 1280
    height: 720

    OpenGlVideoQtQuick {

    }
}
```

Here's a part of OpenGlVideoQtQuick:

```
class OpenGlVideoQtQuick : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal t READ t WRITE setT NOTIFY tChanged)

public:
    OpenGlVideoQtQuick();

    qreal t() const { return m_t; }
    void setT(qreal t);
    Q_INVOKABLE void initRtspMedia(const QString &uri);
}
```

How do I call `initRtspMedia()` from QML right at the creation of the `OpenGlVideoQtQuick` QML object? I've only seen how can buttons and other things call C++ code, but not how to call it immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case you can use [Component.onCompleted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import A 1.0

Item {

    width: 1280
    height: 720

    OpenGlVideoQtQuick {
        id: opengl_video
        Component.onCompleted: opengl_video.initRtspMedia("some uri")
    }
}
```

---

Or from C++ you can do it with the help of [QQmlParserStatus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlparserstatus.html):

```
class OpenGlVideoQtQuick : public QQuickItem, public QQmlParserStatus
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal t READ t WRITE setT NOTIFY tChanged)
    Q_INTERFACES(QQmlParserStatus)
public:
    OpenGlVideoQtQuick();

    qreal t() const { return m_t; }
    void setT(qreal t);
    Q_INVOKABLE void initRtspMedia(const QString &uri);

   void classBegin() {}
   void componentComplete() {
       initRtspMedia("some uri");
   }
}
```